# Next Line in less

Tags: shell, vim

I'm using less and since I have long lines I need some way of going to the next line (I mean the real next line, not the next line shown in less which might be the continuation of the previous line)

shortcut  seems to go to the next visible line and not next real line.

Moreover I cannot use vim because of the large file size.

Comment: Can you show some examples. Pressing `enter` shows you next line in `less`

Comment: It shows. but consider a long line splitted into 10000 less lines. Enter goes to the next line among those 10000 lines not the next real line

Answer (score 6):

tl;dr: `/^`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>n</kbd>+.

Proof:

```
$ xterm -geometry 8x5
```

Paste these commands one by one in the new window:

```
$ PS1='$ '
$ cd -- "$(mktemp -d)"
$ for line in {0..9}
do
    printf %s- "$line"
    for column in {0..9}
    do
        printf $column
    done
    printf '\n'
done > test.txt
$ less test.txt
```

Now the terminal looks like this:

```
0-012345678
9
1-012345678
9
test.txt
```

Go to the next line by pressing `/^` + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (which just finds the start of the *first* line) and then pressing <kbd>n</kbd> to find the next match:

```
1-012345678
9
2-012345678
9
:
```

Now you can press <kbd>n</kbd> to go to the next line in the file, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd> to go to the previous line.

This works regardless of whether `less` is actually wrapping lines, and is only one character press once the search has been done.

Answer (score 3):

Navigating horizontally away from column 0 will inhibit line wrapping, so simply navigate right one step, down one line, and then back to column 0.

Comment: was not successful. Do you mean simply pressing right arrow. Then down arrow, then do whatever I want? I tried it. But no success. Moreover, it seems very strange if what you say is correct! It looks like a magic password, instead of a shortcut

Comment: Right, down, and then left.

Comment: This did not work. Right, down, left, then ctrl+g, then up and down